# Pass variable from JSP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Inside a JSP, I am fetching data from a Servlet by this code

```
<%
String name=(String)request.getAttribute("filepath");
%>
```

I want to access this inside script tags, how should i go about it?
I tried this `var n = "${name}"` and `var n = "<%=name%>"` and it did not work.

Comment: Can you show us the location of your scriptlet code in the web page?

Comment: What error came up when you tried that?

Comment: var n = "<%=name%>" It should be work. try  var n = '<%=name%>';

Answer (score 0):

Both options should work fine (do not forget the ;).
Just remember that the scriptlet/ EL are executed when the page is returned from the server and the JavaScript when the browser parse the HTML.

To debug this issue I would use scriptlet first and look if I have a value using browser "view source". 
If you do not see any value i.e.

```
var n = "";
```

You did not set the attribute correctly in java.
As for EL usage. Make sure you have the correct setting, in older version EL was disabled by default see 
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/modelandviews-model-value-is-not-displayed-in-jsp-via-el/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the assignment in scriptlet is working. Try *System.out.println(name);* to see if the value is set correctly.

I often use the latter

```
var n = "<%=name%>";
```